# Send tap command to qt app running on embedded display

Tags: python, c++, qt

I'm trying to send a tap command to my qt application running on linux embedded display. Last time I used adb commands to send tap commands to my android application. Now I want to do the same for my qt application that runs on Linux embedded display. I tried many methods but with no luck. I'm accessing my display via putty using the ethernet connection.

In putty I run the following command:  cat /dev/input/touchscreen0 | hexdump. When I taped on the display, it printed many hex numbers. I'm not sure how to decode it or send tap command from putty. I appreciate any help.

Comment: QML or Widgets?

Comment: I want to test the widgets.

Comment: Ah. In that case, I think you need to look into the QGestureEvent class: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgestureevent.html. Good luck.

Comment: Take a look into Squish.